# Difference between serializing and deserializing and writing internals to a file and then reading them and passing them in constructor

Tags: java, serialization

Lets say we have a class

```
Class A implements serializable{

    String s;
    int i;
    Date d;

    public A(){
    }

    public A(String s, int i, Date d){
        this.s =s;
       blah blah
    }
}
```

Now lets say one way i store all the internal values of s,i,d to a file and read them again, and pass them to the constructor and create a new object. Second I serialize and then deserialize to a new object. What is the basic difference between the two approaches.

I know serialization will be slow and secure and the other approach is not. Any other differences.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the formatting help (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) when posting questions (a summary of the info is also shown just to the right of the question area). You should be able to use the "edit" link under your question to fix the formatting.

Answer (score 5):

Read this article, explains pretty good what is serialization about (it is for Java RMI but the serialization explanation and problems are the same): http://oreilly.com/catalog/javarmi/chapter/ch10.html

The main differences I see is that:

- (As the other answers says) you are responsible to serialize - deserialize. What is going to happen when one of the properties is another big complex class? What are you going to do then? Save its value as well?
- Serialization depends on reflection, while the file thing depends on getters/setters/constructors. With reflection you don't need public setters/getters or a constructor with parameters. With the file thing you need them.

Extracted from the link above:

### Using Serialization

*Serialization* is a mechanism built into the core Java libraries for writing a graph of objects into a stream of data. This stream of data can then be programmatically manipulated, and a deep copy of the objects can be made by reversing the process. This reversal is often called *deserialization*.

In particular, there are three main uses of serialization:

- **As a persistence mechanism**. If the stream being used is `FileOutputStream`, then the data will automatically be written to a file.
- **As a copy mechanism**. If the stream being used is `ByteArrayOutputStream`, then the data will be written to a byte array in memory. This byte array can then be used to create duplicates of the original objects.
- **As a communication mechanism**. If the stream being used comes from a socket, then the data will automatically be sent over the wire to the receiving socket, at which point another program will decide what to do.

The important thing to note is that the use of serialization is independent of the serialization algorithm itself. If we have a serializable class, we can save it to a file or make a copy of it simply by changing the way we use the output of the serialization mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

In your first approach, *you* are responsible for maintaining the logical relationship between the data values (in the sense that *you* store the data and then read it back and construct the object back).

In the second approach, Java does this for you behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

**Serialization and Deserialization in Java**

Serialization is a process by which we can store the state of an object into any storage medium. We can store the state of the object into a file, into a database table etc. Deserialization is the opposite process of serialization where we retrieve the object back from the storage medium.

Eg1: Assume you have a Java bean object and its variables are having some values. Now you want to store this object into a file or into a database table.     This can be achieved using serialization. Now you can retrieve this object again from the file or database at any point of time when you need it. This can be achieved using deserialization: (Post by Bobin Goswami).

Answer (score 0):

Not real difference other than that you are implementing a custom serialization scheme, so that will typically involve more code, since by default serialization requires just an interface declaration.

You can achieve something very similar with Externalizable - you are in control of exactly what data is saved, so you can choose to save just the constructor arguments and construct the object from that. (You could achieve this also with serialization by marking non-constructor arguments as transient.)

Answer (score 0):

The section on Serialization in Joshua Bloch's Effective Java, 2nd Ed. is really a good read on this subject.  Something that is very important to keep in mind:

1. Using your own homegrown persistence method is intralinguistic.  When you read data back from a store, you control how an object's state is restored.  Very often this is with constructors and/or static factories.  The invariants of the object's state are preserved.  Encapsulation is maintained because you don't necessarily need to disclose implementation details as part of the custom store.  The downside, of course, is that data very often needs to go places and @pakore nicely outlined those situations in which serialization is useful.
2. Serialization is an extralinguistic mechanism.  Bloch makes compelling arguments for why serialization (in particular, the Serializiable interface) should be invoked only with the greatest of care.  Serialization can bypass constructors because reconstitution of objects does not depend on one.  There are profound possible security concerns.  The invariants of your object's state are vulnerable.  Moreover, using Serializable tends to lock you into supporting a particular class implementation (i.e., it destroys encapsulation) because much of your object's state becomes part of the class's exported API once it becomes Serializable (this can be proactively deferred by marking certain instance fields as transient).

TL;DR: Serialization is a common and even fundamental aspect of modern Java-based computing.  Data these days must go places, and serialization provides a commonly used mechanism for communication.  Because of the vulnerabilities that serialization may invoke and because it may case much (or all) of your object's internal state to become part of its exported API, the Serializable interface should be used with the greatest of care.